# Specific PostgresSql version installation in Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos

I want to install PostgreSql 11.17 in MAC for my work. But I am seeing PostgreSql 11.18 available here - https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads . How can I install 11.17 version specific?

I got source files - https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v11.17/ , but don't know which one to install.

Comment: Why use 11.17 and miss [the 30 bug fixes](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=11.17&to=11.18) from the patch version 11.18? Both will work just the same (unless you are relying on a bug/problem that exists in 11.17 that does not longer exist in 11.18). You should always use the [latest minor release](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/): "*For minor releases, the community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading.*" - so using 11.17 is riskier than using 11.18

Comment: Yes have realised the same and went for 11.18 version only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install a specific version, e.g. postgresql 11.17 you simply run:

```
brew install postgresql@11.17
```